# hover over wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hover, mouseover

So I have been struggling with making a picture change to another during hover over but it won't budge. I am using a WordPress theme hosted on godaddy so I'm not used to the code.
Here is the code in place:

```
<header id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php get_option_tree('rb_logo_path', $theme_options, true); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
        </a>
</div>
<p id="tagline"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your HTML to this:

```
<header id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
            <img class="default-image" src="<?php get_option_tree('rb_logo_path', $theme_options, true); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
            <img class="hover-only" src="%%OTHER IMAGE URL%%" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
        </a>
</div>
<p id="tagline"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p>
</header>
```

In your `style.css`

```
#logo a img.default-image {
    display: block;
}
#logo a img.hover-only {
    display: none;
}
#logo a:hover img.hover-only {
    display: block;
}
#logo a:hover img.default-image {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the mouse over event (for instance using jQuery) and replace the image.

```
   $('logo').bind('mouseover', function() {
       $('img').attr("src","<other image url>");
   }
```

You will need to add this code to your theme sources.